# Use Javascript to Fetch a Variable from a Separate PHP File

Tags: javascript, php, server-sent-events

I've seen many posts related to what I'm asking, but I can't seem to find an appropriate answer, and I'll admit I'm a n000b to both Javascript and PHP. I've followed some tutorials, but I can't seem to do what I want:

I have a HTML document that is subscribing to a SSE like so:

`var eventSource = new EventSource("http://thewebsite.com/events/?access_token=" + accessToken);`

I don't want to put the accessToken in the HTML page because it's insecure, so I'd like to hide the access token in a separate PHP file in the same directory, something like this:

code.php

```
<?php
     $accessToken = "12345ABCDE";
?>
```

I can't figure out how to write the javascript to ask code.php for the accessToken.

Comment: You want Javascript to do a http request?  That's would be Ajax.

Comment: That's not really going to give you any added security. It's only minorly obscuring the token. To gain any type of added security you would need to create a server side mechanism to hit the URL using the token and then pass the results back to your JS.

Answer (score 0):

echo should do the trick:

fetch.php

```
<?PHP
    echo "12345ABCDE";
?>
```

but you need to use ajax to call the php:

```
$.post("fetch.php",function(data){access(data);},"text");
```

or

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "fetch.php",
    success: function(data){access(data);},
    dataType: "text"
});
```

using token:

```
function access(incoming){
    var eventSource = new EventSource("http://thewebsite.com/events/?access_token=" + incoming);
}
```

how safe it is to output your token from PHP is another story, but at least that's how it can be done.

Comment: Probably better to not assume people are using jQuery